# How to limit query to 3 most recent posts with sanity?

Tags: sanity, groq

I am trying to query the 3 most recent article posts but not sure how to set the limit

```
"latestArticles": *[_type == "article" && wasDeleted != true && isDraft != true] | order(publishDate desc){
  title,
  _createdAt,
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can slice your query by adding array with start and end index at the end of query, so it would look like this in your case:

```
"latestArticles": *[_type == "article" && wasDeleted != true && isDraft != true] | order(publishDate desc){
  title,
  _createdAt
}[0...2] // get entries 0, 1, and 2 (3 total)
```

There is section dedicated to this in sanity [documentation](https://www.sanity.io/docs/how-queries-work#16b34b599b2f)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How would you ensure it doesn't query the current article page you are on?

Comment: I guess you could filter out results by id, so you would need to add  `_id != "articleIdHere"` inside square brackets. There is cheat sheet for filtering provided by sanity - https://www.sanity.io/docs/query-cheat-sheet#3949cadc7524